# Activate/deactivate WiFi on Lenovo B5400 under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have a Lenovo B5400 with Ubuntu 14.04 x64. The Ethernet port works fine. How can I enable/disable the WiFi connection? I have no hardware button for this functionality. Under Windows I can press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and a dialog window appears, but I cannot find this functionality under Linux.

`lspci | grep Network` produces:

> 04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

The answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489525/activate-deactivate-wifi-on-lenovo-b5400-under-ubuntu-14-04) is incomplete. Any other ideas?

**EDIT #1:**
The output of `rfkill list all` is:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes

1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

PS: disclaimer: [crossposting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489525/activate-deactivate-wifi-on-lenovo-b5400-under-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Even if your wireless card is disabled, it will be shown by `lspci`, because `lspci` is supposed to show all hardware connected. When `rfkill` says that it is _hard blocked_, that should mean it has been disabled at the hardware level. When I press _Fn + F5_ in my Linux system, no dialog appears, but the kernel disables or enables the wireless card. Try pressing _Fn + F5_ again and checking the output of `rfkill list all`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The Fn+F5 does not change the rfkill output, I still get the "Hard blocked: yes" status. If I press that combination in Windows and then reboot in Ubuntu, the phy0 interface now appears as "Hard blocked: no". Clearly, I would like to avoid these OS switches.

Comment: Try `rfkill unblock wifi` as root.

Comment: Still appears as hard blocked.

Comment: And `sudo rfkill unblock phy0` or `sudo rfkill unblock wlan`?

Comment: Sorry, still no luck :(. Note: instead of phy0 I specified the index of phy0, namely 2 in my case.

Comment: What is the output of `grep rfkill /var/log/syslog` and `grep rfkill /var/log/daemon.log`?

Comment: The output for the first command is given at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XC-g7BX__c_nGOHOJCpkdv6Bwfwhxv-oyaKGoC3WZec/edit?usp=sharing . The second command finishes with grep: /var/log/daemon.log: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm sorry, nothing useful yet. My last try: `egrep 'rtl|WiFi' /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Thanks for your patience. The output is at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SK0o16L3F2v7a1lcd7x2IsCV1PiW-53lG-zGU7Ok8y4/edit?usp=sharing .

Comment: I actually can't see anything wrong in your logs. I've done a few tests with `rfkill` and, at least on my machine, it blocks/unblocks only at the software level, so it may not be of much help for you. For the hardware, I believe the kernel is not recognizing your `Fn` key combo properly. If that is not difficult for you, you could try other kernel, or other distro that doesn't use the Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. For now, I have to stay with Ubuntu (sorry, not yet a Linux geek). The dirty trick is to stay with wireless activated from Windows and reboot; this way Linux sees the wireless device. That's weird, because a lot of laptops are sold without Windows software preinstalled.

Comment: _If that's difficult for you_ = _If you have the time or bandwidth available_. There are many user friendly LiveCDs out there that you can use just to test your hardware without installing them, like __Debian__, which is very stable, and __openSUSE__ or __Mageia__, which are more bleeding-edge. There is also __Mint__, which is well known for being very user friendly, but I don't know whether it uses the Ubuntu kernel or not.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem with my lenovo. Running the following solved my issue:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
$ sudo rfkill unblock all
$ rfkill list all
```

Comment: Consider adding explanations (or documentation links) for each command for completeness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I still get:  0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes